# Peer interview after job application

Tags: interviewing

I recently had a "peer interview" as part of a job application, by phone after Google Meet decided to not cooperate. I am absolutely qualified for the job, with the record to prove it, so my skills were not in question.

The two interviewers were the team leader and a staffer in the team. The interview went poorly and I didn't get the job. It seemed that the team leader seemed to have no interest in the interview from the start.

Her tone was flat and and she just acknowledged my answers to her questions with a unenthusiastic "great!".  She never asked any follow-up questions or clarifications.  The second interviewer barely said anything.

Why would interviewers act this way?
Is there something I can do to get feedback?
How should I deal with interviewers who come across as flat, or disinterested?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123560/discussion-on-question-by-moohbear-peer-interview-after-job-application).

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of reasons why things could have gone this way.

- There is a Clear and Intended (C&I) candidate internally, but the company has a policy where they have to interview externals anyway. (for government jobs, this is common)
- They have interviewed people already who are more promising candidates, who have better resumes than you, but still wanted to interview you.
- The peers were not prepped to interview you (this happens)
- For some reason, there was just no connection or chemistry

Your resume tells them that you can probably do the **work** non-peer interviews confirm or refute that, and peer interviews confirm whether or not you can do the **job**

There is an over-used term which is "good fit".  That's what the peer interview is about, and the decision is usually made within the first thirty seconds.  There are also some dirty tricks that get pulled during them.  Sometimes they will deliberately do things to throw you off of your game to see how you react.  This includes long silence, feigned apathy, and even odd questions to see how you react to stress.

Any of the above could be why this could have broken this way.  Add the fact that in-person interviews are almost non existent at this time, and they were probably off of their game as well.

Comment: While it's just speculation of course, bullet point 1 fits the OP description perfectly. Certain large universities have such a policies as well...  Not the candidate's fault, no need to feel bad.

Comment: @PeteW I worked for a certain company known for their industrial index that would post next to the job listing if there was a clear and intended candidate.

Comment: In the cases I'm thinking of, it seems to come from a conflict between a number of policies relating to internal career development and EOE, both of which are genuine and well intentioned, but the net result is they would be taking a risk by telling the applicant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that one of the goals of a peer interview is to see how you would fit in personality-wise with the rest of the team.  Yes, you may have the best experience and job knowledge, but there is a social aspect to most jobs...especially if you are part of a team.  If they don't feel that you would fit in, for whatever reason, that may be why they seemed uninterested.

> Someone thought my resume was worth an interview, but the interviewers either didn't care or sabotaged me.

Or someone else may have had a much better resume and/or better rapport with the peer interviewer.  Sometimes, you are not the best candidate for the role and you need to simply accept that and move on.

Comment: That was the first interview. How anyone is supposed to have a rapport with people whom they don't know and don't know them, if the same people have no interest discussing  in the first place.

Comment: @Moohbear: If they didn't provide you the opportunity to, then you weren't supposed to.

Comment: @Moohbear, Usually, that decision is made within the first one or two minutes of the interview, but the interviewer is forced to sit there for the rest of the interview because of social conventions. Have you practiced doing many mock interviews with others? If you haven't, I'd suggest you do so on http://pramp.com/

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk Can't say I've practiced mock interviews, but I've had a few real ones. The job is a highly skilled position at the PhD/master+exp level, with a particular skill set. Not really a lof of openings at any given time, and not tons of qualified candidates either.

Comment: @Moohbear, Another thing, not all interviewers are going to be perfect. Many times, an interviewer is pulled from doing their own important work to interview someone, that 95% of the time, is not going to be hired. So don't be surprised when some interviewers are cranky, tired, or disinterested in the interview itself. That happens. As long as this doesn't happen to you with every interview, I think that's fine.